# JQuery Validation Plugin: Change element on error

Tags: jquery, validation

Am using the jQuery Validation plugin, found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), which is proving very useful....

However what I would like to do, is instead of adding the class error to the input of any invalid form field. I would like to the class error to a div next to the form field itself. Here is the HTML..

```
 <div class="label">Surname</div>
 <div><input name="sSurname" id="sSurname" type="text" class="text_field required"></div>
```

So when the form field is invalid on blur, the error class is added to the input field, and when the form is valid, the error class is removed. I would like to add the same functionality to the div with class label, next to the form field..

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey, there is a setting for this in the JQuery Validation plugin file. Search for errorElement: "label" and change it to errorElement: "div"

Thanks